# Accessing an element of this type in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I am unable to figure out what does this mean:

```
my $abc= @{xyz-> pqr-> tuv ('mango', 
                            'orange' => $efg{hello},)};
```

If I want to access the element orange how can I do that. And what does the above mean? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Where does this code come from? A bit of context would help.

Answer (score 1):

Inside out:

`xyz`

Call the function `xyz`

`->pqr`

Take the returned object from xyz, and call its `pqr` method.

`->tuv('mango', 'orange' => $efg{hello}),)`

Take the returned object from the `xyz->pqr` call, and call its `tuv` method with three parameters: `mango`, `orange`, and the value of the `hello` key of `%efg`.

`@{ ... }`

Take the returned array reference from `tuv`, and dereference it.

`$abc = @{ ... }`

assign that dereferenced array in scalar context to `$abc` - this effectively just counts the number of elements returned, while discarding the actual elements.

But I don't understand what you mean by `access the element orange` - there is no element orange here.